# What to beware of reading old Numarray tutorials and examples?

Tags: numpy

Python currently uses Numpy for heavy duty math and image processing.

The earlier Numeric and Numarray are obsolete, but still today there are many tutorials, notes, sample code and other documentation using them.  Some of these cover special topics of interest, some are well written but haven't been updated or replaced, or are otherwise of use.  Quite a bit is the same between Numeric, Numarray and Numpy, so I usually get good mileage out these older docs.   Ocassionaly, though, I run into a line of code that results in error.   Not often enough to remember how to get around it, but usually I figure it out at the cost of some time.

What are the main things to watch out for when relying on such older documentation for current Numpy use? Is there a list of how to translate the differences that exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two good resources:

1. [Numarray to numpy guide](http://www.stsci.edu/resources/software_hardware/numarray/numarray2numpy.pdf)
2. [Differences between Numeric and numpy](http://www.scipy.org/Converting_from_Numeric)

Comment: Aha! I hadn't realized numeric and numpy used different typechars; just thought it was people being inconsistent.